# Count records with a condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, count, conditional-statements, cdata

I have an xml with this structure:

```
<emails>
<record>
    <field name="host"><![CDATA[yahoo]]></field>
    <field name="user"><![CDATA[abc]]></field>
</record>
<record>
    <field name="host"><![CDATA[gmail]]></field>
    <field name="user"><![CDATA[abc]]></field>
</record>
<record>
    <field name="host"><![CDATA[yahoo]]></field>
    <field name="user"><![CDATA[cdx]]></field>
</record>
</emails>
```

And, I want to count the number of records where host = yahoo.
I know that I need to use count(), but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Are your CDATA tags correct here? They should probably be written as `<![CDATA[yahoo]]>` not `![CDATA[yahoo]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you were positioned on the **emails** element, this is the expression you probably want

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(record[field[@name='host']/text()='yahoo'])" />
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/emails">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(record[field[@name='host']/text()='yahoo'])" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming your XML was well formed, and your CDATA tags were correctly formatted, it should output 3.